# Loading .BAT for Multiple Subfolders

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a problem : I have a .bat file that makes loading a database, however , he can only do this when copied to the same folder where the database . As I have multiple databases in various subfolders in a folder "Data", I am copying the .bat for all subfolders . This is really need ? How can I make the .bat function independently of folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's extremely unlikely that your database-creation batch file needs to be in the same directory as your database-to-be, but it;s not impossible.

Try

```
pushd "?:\wherever\your\database\needs\to\be\created"
call "?:\wherever\your\database\creation\executable\resides\database_creation_batch_name.bat"
popd
```

This should work.

If it does, then what you need to do is to place the database-creation batch "on the path".

from the prompt, execute `path`

This will show a semicolon-separated list of directories. Simply copy the `.bat` file to any one of them, and thereafter

```
database_creation_batch_name
```

will create your database in the current directory. Note that within a batch file, you would need to execute `call database_creation_batch_name`.

If that doesn't work, then post a relevant sample of the batch here for analysis by editing it into your initial post.

Comment: There's nothing apparent in the code that should prevent the routine from being executed in the manner I've outlined **but** it would be a good idea to add a line `setlocal` just after the `@echo off` in that batch, otherwise `path` will be needlessly extended every time your posted routine is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a command-line argument which specifies the path you want the batch script to operate in. Google for "batch file arguments".